# How to delpoy Vue project to production?

Tags: nginx, vue.js, deployment, web-deployment

Using Ubuntu 16.04 and Nginx I am trying to deploy a Vue project to production but keep running against a white wall- literally.

I cloned my project to

```
/var/www/html/maak-web/maak_web/
```

Installed all needed dependencies with `npm install` and ran the following build script:

```
node build/build.js
```

This started the `building for production` which was successful and the project deployed.

In my nginx default config I changed the root to point to the correct folder like so:

```
root /var/www/html/maak-web/maak_web;
```

When I now visit my domain/IP I see that the project loads (e.g. favicon and site name loads) as well as I can access my `static` files from here:

https://mysitedomain.com/static

It seems the Vue project works but the problem is that it doesn't actually display anything and visiting sub views like `/oneview` and `/anotherview` throw 404 page not found errors.

Since Vue doesn't seem to throw any errors I suspect its the nginx configuration problem!?

Comment: did the build script created a index.html at all? Does the ngi x config the site block for picking up index.hrml files?

Comment: It created 'dist' folder and index.html. What do you mean by 'does the nginx block the site by picking up index.html'?

Comment: did you use Vue router then the mode is **history**?

Comment: what happens if you visit `#/anotherview` instead of `/anotherview`?

Comment: Thanks @Daniel it seems that I completely missed the point. The solution was to build the production into /dist/ folder and publish only the /dist/ folder content. Once I copied the content to /www/html/ it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

> The solution was to build the production into /dist/ folder and publish only the /dist/ folder content. Once I copied the content to /www/html/ it worked fine.

seeing that this was an error with not getting the right files to the output folder, i suggest you update your `config/index.js` file to include the correct production location there by setting `index` and `assetsRoot` for the `build` object

```
  build: {

    // Template for index.html
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../srv/www/index.html'),

    // Paths
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../srv/www'),
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
    ...
```